# md-chips with md-select in multi select mode

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

When I am trying to generate md-chips on selecting multiple values from md-select, It is not working. Does md-chips works only with autocomplete analyser and input field?

```
<md-chips ng-model="launchAPIQueryParams.type">
   <md-select name="launchCalType" ng-model="launchAPIQueryParams.type" 
                       multiple="true" placeholder="Launch Type"
                       md-on-close='applylaunchFilter("type")'>
        <md-option ng-repeat="typeOption in launchTypeOptions" ng-value="typeOption[1]">
                  {{typeOption[0]}}
         </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-chips>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer: No. 
`<md-chips>` component will only takes `<input>` or `<md-autocomplete>` into its transcluded context.

However, the same thing can be achieved with `md-autocompelet`.
The key is set `md-min-length` on `<md-autocomplete>` to 0 so it will auto show the menu just like what a `<md-select>` menu would be. 
Here's an example:

```
// controller.js
angular
  .moduel('mdChipsDemo', [])
  .controller('MdChipsDemoCtrl', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.selectedOption = '';
    vm.searchText = '';
    vm.launchAPIQueryParams = {
        types: [],
    };

    vm.launchTypeOptions = [
        {name: 'Op1', value: 1},
        {name: 'Op2', value: 2},
        {name: 'Op3', value: 3},
        {name: 'Op4', value: 4},
    ];
});

// template.html
<div ng-app="mdChipsDemo" ng-controller="MdChipsDemoCtrl as vm">
<md-chips ng-model="vm.launchAPIQueryParams.types">
  <md-autocomplete
            md-selected-item="vm.selectedOption"
            md-search-text="vm.searchText"
            md-items="typeOption in vm.launchTypeOptions"
            md-item-text="typeOption.name"
            md-min-length="0"
            placeholder="Search for a launchTypeOptions">
      <span md-highlight-text="vm.searchText">{{typeOption.name}}</span>
  </md-autocomplete>
  <md-chip-template>
    <span>{{$chip.name}}</span>
  </md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
</div>
```

If your ultimate goal is to have multiple select ability, `<md-autocomplete>` also expose `<md-item-template>` where you can put your `<md-select>` in. Check the [doc for md-autocomplete](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete) and you will see.

Or if you really insist on using `<select>`, there's an 3rd-party component on npm calls `md-chips-select` which does what you want.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/md-chips-select